# How to rotate an entire collection with one pivot point?

Tags: modeling, collections

It probably has to do with the way I organized (or not) my outliner but I basically need to rotate the tunnel with all the other objects following it. When I try to do it, all the elements rotate in different ways separating the scene.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried snapping the cursor to the tunnel, then changing the rotation mode to rotate around the cursor?

Comment: Yes, I did. The elements still act weird. Isn't there a way to rotate the entire group as a single object like in every other program with layers?

Comment: Have you set the transform pivot point to bounding box?

Comment: That was it! Please write it as an answer so I can select it! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your *Transform Orientation* may be set to *Local* or some other setting.

[image]

Try *Global* to lock to the scene axes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. That had already happened once and this time, it is set to Global.